# PHP: How to use Regular Expression in PHP to Split String in 2

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

How would I use regular expression with PHP to split the following string into 2 pars as depicted below:

String to be split: `4x330ml`

Split into `4x330` and `ml`

I have tried the following but it does not return the accurate data:

```
$pdata = "4x330ml"
$data = preg_split('#(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])#i', $pdata);
```

Then I get something like `4` in `$data[0]` and `x330` in `$data[1]`

EDIT: Please note that `ml` could also be `cm`, `kg`, etc. A little complicated, which I don't seem to find a solution.

EDIT: Also I have tried the following regex (which I prefer to use at this point) with incomplete results:

```
$pdata = "5x500ml";
$data = preg_split('/(\d+\.?\d+)|(\w+)i/', $pdata);
```

This returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5x
    [1] => ml
)
```

`500` from that string is not being returned...

Thanks,

Comment: Do you really have to use regex?

Comment: I don't have to. Actually, anything to reach the right solution

Comment: But what is your given criteria for splitting the string?
Is it always ml?

Comment: No.. I should have pointed that out in the question. But it could also be `cm`, `kg`.

Comment: Now you have two problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use preg_match:

```
$pdata = "4x330ml";
preg_match('/(\d+x\d+)(.*)/',$pdata, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4x330ml
    [1] => 4x330
    [2] => ml
)
```

Comment: Perfect! This solution is similar to the preg_split that I had provided, but better. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You said it could be ml, cm, or kg. and that you don't have to use regex. So, assuming it is always 2 characters at the end, a very simple way to do this would be:

```
$string = "4x330ml";
$part1 = substr($string, 0, -2); //returns 4x330
$part2 = substr($string, -2, 2); //returns "ml"
```

Answer (score 3):

This ought to give you what you want.

```
$pdata = "4x330cm";

$data = preg_match('/([^(ml|cm|kg)]*)(ml|cm|kg)/', $pdata, $group);

echo $group[0].' ';
echo $group[1].' ';
echo $group[2].' ';
```

Use the `preg_match` function, and store the results into an array.  The 0 index will return the entire matched string.  The `$group[1]` will return just "4x330".  The `$group[2]$` will return just the "cm".

Comment: I like this idea, but it is returning an error `PHP Warning:  preg_split(): Unknown modifier '|'`

Comment: I think you're missing the regex delimiters at the beginning and end of the string. Usually you would use `/`.

Comment: This new solution does not work... I am looking to see if I can generate a solution using regex

Comment: What do you think this part `[^(ml|cm|kg)]*` means?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the units will always be 2 characters long you can use this

```
$pdata = "4x330ml";
$strNumber = substr($pdata, 0, strlen($pdata)-2);
$strUnit = substr($pdata, strlen($pdata)-2,2);
echo $strNumber;  //returns 4x330
echo $strUnit; //returns ml
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this without a regex

```
$string = '4x330ml';
$splitPoint = strrpos($string,'m');
$firstPart = substr($string,0,$string); //gets 4x330
$secondPart = substr($string,$splitPoint); //gets ml
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by using the following code:

```
$data = "4x500ml";
$pdata = preg_split('/(\d+x\d+)/', $data, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Which now prints:

```
array(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 4x500
    [2] => ml
)
```

It looks like it is capturing the delimeter as array[1] and since the delimeter is actually the first section of the string I want to split, it is fine for now, until I find a better solution.

Thank you all for trying.